# Looping through multiple/different xml elements in their order with F# data

Tags: f#, f#-data

---

Is it possible to loop through the following document in order using F#, pseudo code is really pseudo :)

```xml
<root>
   <element_a>1</element_a>
   <element_b>2</element_b>
   <element_c>3</element_c>
   <element_a>4</element_a>
</root>
```

pseudo code:

```
root.? |> Array.iter ( fun e ->
   printfn "%s:%s" e.DisplayName e.Value
)
```

Result:

```
element_a:1
element_b:2
element_c:3
element_a:4
```

So,

1. can I loop through different elements in the original order?
2. if yes, how do I know which element it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML type provider does not give you any typed way of doing this. That said, making it possible to access all children in order as a collection of some provided types would be a useful extension!

However, you can use the underlying `XElement` representation to iterate over all the children and then turn them back to the statically-typed representation generated by the XML type provider.

Using your basic example, the type of all the elements is inferred as `int`, so that's not all that interesting (there are no children...), but say you have something like this where different elements all have the same child element `a` with attribute `n`:

```
type Demo = XmlProvider<"""<root>
   <element_a><a n="foo" /></element_a>
   <element_b><a n="bar" /></element_b>
   <element_c><a n="zoo" /></element_c>
   <element_a><a n="goo" /></element_a>
</root>""">
```

You can now get the elements in an untyped way using `root.XElement.Descendants()`:

```
let root = Demo.GetSample()
for child in root.XElement.Descendants() do
  let asA = new Demo.ElementA(child)
  printfn "%A" asA.A.N
```

Once we have the child element, we re-wrap it into a statically typed representation. Here, we always use the type generated for `<element_a>` (which may be wrong - if other elements have different structure, but it works nicely here).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was hoping that I wouldn't have to use the XElement, but it does the job! 
I didn't know about the new Demo.ElementA(child), so that made my code a lot nicer.

Answer (score 0):

You can biuld an `XDocument` and iterate through the chilren of the root:

```
#r "System.XML.Linq"
open System.IO;
open System.Xml.Linq;

let xml = @"
            <root>
               <element_a>1</element_a>
               <element_b>2</element_b>
               <element_c>3</element_c>
               <element_a>4</element_a>
            </root>"
let xdoc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xml))
let rootEl = xdoc.Elements() |> Seq.head
rootEl.Elements() |> Seq.iter (fun el -> printfn "%s: %s" el.Name.LocalName el.Value)
```

Should produce the desired output.

If you want to distinguish between elements of the same name, you can swap `Seq.iter` with `Seq.iteri`, that passes the ordinal index to the supplied function:

```
rootEl.Elements() |> Seq.iteri (fun idx el -> printfn "Idx %d: %s: %s" idx el.Name.LocalName el.Value)
```

produces:

```
Idx 0: element_a: 1
Idx 1: element_b: 2
Idx 2: element_c: 3
Idx 3: element_a: 4
```